# AppleScript - "Close tabs to right of current tab" in Google Chrome

Tags: applescript, google-chrome

I managed to make this script work but I think it can be improved further.

Can anyone advise me

- How it can be refactored?
- Why I cannot run `close tabs whose id is not in closeTabList`. (It will return `can’t make {y, x} into type specifier` error)

Here's the script:

```
tell window 1 of application "Google Chrome"
    set canCloseTab to false
    set closeTabList to {}
    
    repeat with t in tabs
        if canCloseTab then
            set end of closeTabList to id of t
        else
            if id of t = id of the active tab then
                set canCloseTab to true
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
    repeat with closeTabId in closeTabList
        close (tabs whose id is closeTabId)
    end repeat
end tell
```

I tried using [this script for Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106944/applescript-close-tabs-to-right-of-current-tab-in-safari-7) but it doesn't work on Google Chrome because AppleScript cannot get the index of the tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following **AppleScript** code should accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

### *This will close the tabs to the right*

```
try
    tell window 1 of application "Google Chrome" to ¬
        close (tabs -1 thru (active tab index + 1))
end try
```

---

### *This will close the tabs to the left*

```
try
    tell window 1 of application "Google Chrome" to ¬
        close (tabs 1 thru (active tab index - 1))
end try
```

Comment: When I first saw the question, I had tried `tell application "Google Chrome" to close tabs ((active tab index of front window) + 1) thru -1 of front window` and for some reason it didn't work, and I focused back on what I was previous working on. Turns out the error was I had the last _tab_ selected and obviously no `try` _statement_. I should have looked harder at the error. Anyway this should definitely be the accepted answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

*Frame challenge…*
I've no idea how to fix the Applescript, sorry, but this seems something of a heavy-handed approach to a function that's already in the menu & can therefore be triggered directly by a simple key command.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @user3439894 - [What's a frame challenge?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6843)